# How to configure MuleSoft with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar, stack-trace, mule-studio

I am trying to create my first MuleSoft application using Maven. I have used CMD to confirm that both Java and Maven are installed. I've also configured my environment variables.

I then open the MuleSoft Anypoint Studio, and create my first named "mulesoft-sample" I select to use Maven, and leave all default settings as they are.

Once I click finish, the Console begins to download a number of files
These continue to be downloaded until after it would seem the near end of the files, it throws an error:

> There was an error running the studio:studio goal on project mulesoft-sample

In Console, I see the errors listed below.

I was originally trying to use the latest version of Maven (3.5.0). However, I found a video tutorial that said 3.3.9 was a verified version for MuleSoft. So I thought perhaps the newest version wasn't supported and instead used 3.3.9. However, it is still failing. I've also tried changing the environment variable to other options, such as going straight to \bin, rather than the complete directory (taking shots in the dark here). Unfortunately, nothing has worked and I'm running out of option.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting these errors, and my build will not succeed? How to correct the error?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

Comment: I've also set up my environment variables: 
JAVA_HOME --> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
M2_HOME --> C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9
MAVEN_HOME --> C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9
Path --> %M2_HOME%\bin
(CONFIRMED -- THOSE ARE THE CORRECT LOCATIONS OF THESE DIRECTORIES)

Comment: In the Console, I see the following: 
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131/../lib/tools.jar @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: mule @ line 9, column 16
 @

Comment: [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.mycompany:mulesoft-sample:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\chris\AnypointStudio\workspace\mulesoft-sample\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: mule @ line 9, column 16
[ERROR]

Comment: [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException

Comment: Please edit the question and add the errors there. Please do not use the comments as part of the question. Comments should be used by other users to request clarifications.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your local maven directory? It should be located at %USERPROFILEM/.m2/repository.

Answer (score 0):

In anypoint studio go on windows>prefernces.then click on java>installed JREs. and add your Java JDK folder and note that only JDK, not JRE. then you can test your maven

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the right java is not pointing with Anypoint Studio . In the studio navigate to windows > preferences the search java. Make sure jdk is selected and not jre . If still problem continues try updating your java and reinstalling maven .

Answer (score 0):

- Download the latest maven on your local machine, then goto **anypoint
  studio windows->preferences->anypoint studio->maven**
- provide the maven path and click **Test Maven configuration**(green
  check mark obtained if the URL is properly provided)

Answer (score 0):

1. Mule Maven Plugin configuration.
   1.1. Use mule mule-app-maven-plugin to build the application.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
        <copyToAppsDirectory>false</copyToAppsDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

No need for additional Mule Maven plugins. 
  This is the default mule plugin set when creating your Mule project on AnyPoint (AP) Studio.

```
1.2. Make sure you set flag copyToAppsDirectory to false. 
       This flag is set to true by default so you must change it manually.
```

2. Maven Dependency Plugin Configuration.
   2.1. Now we need to add a plugin to copy the generated artifact to the MULE_HOME/apps directory, i.e. to deploy the application to the standalone local mule server.
          We will use the maven-dependency-plugin. 
          Just add these plugin after the mule maven plugin section in your application pom.xml.

```
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.mule.support.ba</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>bonmarche-case-00145615</artifactId>
                                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                                        <type>zip</type>
                                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>C:/mule-home/apps</outputDirectory>
                                        <destFileName>bonmarche-case.zip</destFileName>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

2.2. Update the attributes within the  tag (in grey) with the corresponding values on your environment.
 2.3. As you see in 2.1, we are configuring the deployment to apps folder on Maven 'deploy' phase. You may choose a different phase to copy the artifact, but it must be bound to any phase after the package phase, so that the artifact exists in the repository.

3. Disable the default execution of Maven Deploy Plugin to prevent deploying the generated artifact to an external repository. This may be changed depending on your project needs.
   Add this plugin after maven-dependency-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

4. Build your application and verify the generated ZIP file is copied to MULE_HOME/apps directory.
           $> mvn clean deploy

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue and got resolved by changing the JRE to JDK in preferences==>java==>Installed JRE's there change to JDK and restarted the any point studio. This resolved the issue to me.