# Doubled bin in Mule Project Java path

Tags: java, maven, jvm, mule, anypoint-studio

**I am running current setup:**

- OS: Win10
- Java: 1.8 AdoptOpenJDK (JDK + JRE)
- Mule: 4.2.1 / Anypoint Studio 7.9
- Maven: embedded in Studio - 3.6.3

**The issue is:**

```
Unable to execute Java command.  The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
"C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot\\bin\\bin\\javaw.exe" -version
Failed to retrieve the version of Java. Resolving to the lowest supported version (1.4).
Launching a JVM...
Unable to execute Java command.  The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
"C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot\\bin\\bin\\javaw.exe"
```

**Win10 environments:**

- `C:\Users\1>echo %JAVA_HOME% - C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot`
- `C:\Users\1>echo %PATH% - C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.8.1-bin\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin;`

**That is a tip from Studio project run below the issue description:**

```
Advice:
Usually when the Wrapper fails to start the JVM process, it is
because of a problem with the value of the configured Java command.
Currently:
wrapper.java.command=C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot\\bin\\bin\\javaw.exe
Please make sure that the PATH or any other referenced environment
variables are correctly defined for the current environment.
```

But it tells me nothing except system env vars but they look correct.

**What I have tried:**

- Checking environment variables (system and user) - everything is fine, also checked with a teammate to be sure
- Anypoint Studio checks: runs correct (1.8) Java, Maven (3.6.3) and Mule (4.2.1)
- Maven and Studio config files - everything is also correct (uses %JAVA_HOME%)

I have no idea where is Studio taking this second "bin" from, thank you for all advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Anypoint Studio has its embedded version of OpenJDK to execute Mule projects. You can select an alternative one from the UI in [Preferences / Java / Installed JREs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.9/change-jdk-config-in-projects) (serves for both JDKs and JREs). It seems that this is the case because the error refers to a JDK installed outside Studio. Ensure that the location of the Java 8 SDKs configured point to the 'home' directory of the JDK (in your case it seems to be C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot) rather than to the bin subdirectory (C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot\bin). Studio will assume the Java executable is under the bin subdirectory of the JDK home.

Comment: Not sure if that solved the issue, but I had, as you mentioned, \bin at the end of java. After removing it the project came up with another error:
`Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occured. Program will exit.`

Comment: This is possibly another issue not related to that one:
`Launching a JVM...
Unrecognized option: -M-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2048m`
That does not allow JVM to run, need to do research, but this is possibly a correct answer - to remove bin from Studio JDK path.

Comment: That issue solved, params were not necessary, there are more problems but not related, to this one, thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

What's about confuguration mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47356035/16625980) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45097590/16625980)?

Seems like IDEs manage JDK in more sophisticated ways, similar steps helped me to configure my IDEA

Comment: That answer asks for JRE to JDK change, I have set JDK only: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot\bin so I don't think thats the point, but I will dive deeper into this tommorow, thanks.

Comment: My point is that you may need to confugure JDK settings in IDE internally.

Comment: That was what I was looking for, but could not find any internal issue, but good point, thanks